# magento 2 : how to use phtml in cms static block

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-block

I want to make a cms static block which should display/render the content of a .phtml file (echo "Test1"). Content of my cms static block:

```
<div id="something">
     {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="test" template="product/view/test1.phtml" }}
</div>
```

something like that. Would this work out ?

Location of "test1.phtml" is in `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\test1.phtml`

Also: what if I change location of "test1.phtml", how can I write it in {{ ... }} ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` basic template.

Try this:

```
<div id="something">
    {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="path/to/my/file.phtml" }}
</div>
```

This should work.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to display product information you have to use blocks from prduct view. Example:

```
<div id="something">
    {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="test" template="path/to/my/file.phtml" }}
</div>
```

PHTML file position depends on your architecture. If you are not embedding this in a module you could put it in your template.

Example:

```
<div id="something">
    {{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::mytemplate.phtml" }}
</div>
```

And put your file under: `design/frontend/yourtheme/default/Magento_Theme/mytemplate.phtml`

Comment: Thanks again ! I'm using `class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"` because I need to display product-sku attribute. One question: `template="var/test1.phtml"` would also work, if that would be it's location ?

Comment: See my updated post

Answer (score 1):

Use class "*Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template*" and you can also pass any value if required:

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" testId="66" template="Magento_Catalog::product/widget/test.phtml"}}
```